# Convert Date to another timezone in JavaScript and Print with Correct Timezone

Tags: javascript, typescript, timezone

I need to convert a local timezone to Pacific/Los angeles.

Example, if user in Hawaii

**Code:** taken here from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127122/15358601

```
function convertTZ(date, tzString) {
    return new Date((typeof date === "string" ? New Date(date) : date).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: tzString}));   
}

convertTZ(new Date(), "America/Los_Angeles")
```

> Sun Mar 14 2021 17:01:59 GMT-1000 (Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time) {}

It still prints the final with Hawaii. I need America/Los Angeles Display, not Hawaii. (however it still prints the correct new Hours and Minutes, just the Display label is incorrect)
How can this be done?

[image: Results picture]

The solution should work for other timezones also, printing it respectively its other timezone, eg: America/New_York, Europe/London, Europe/Paris, etc ,

Comment: are you looking for library like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions ?

Comment: hi @Dhara if Mozilla is standardized and will work in Chrome, Edge, and Angular 11 with no issues, I'm open to it, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

- The approach in the answer you linked to for the `convertTZ` is flawed.  One should not parse the output of `toLocalString` with the `Date` constructor.  Please read the comments following that answer.
- The `Date` object *can not* be converted to another time zone, because it is not actually in *any* time zone.  The only thing encapsulated by the `Date` object is its Unix timestamp, which can be seen with `.valueOf()`, `.getTime()`, or any mechanism that coerces it to a `Number`.  Such values are always UTC-based.
- When you see local time or a time zone coming from the `Date` object, the system's local time zone is applied to the internal UTC-based Unix Timestamp to create the output.  The local time zone cannot be changed programmatically from JavaScript (or TypeScript), nor can it be altered on a per-object basis.
- Instead of trying to convert a `Date` object in one time zone to a `Date` object in another time zone, recognize that all `Date` objects are inherently UTC.  Thus, you can create a *string* that is in a different time zone, (for example, using `toLocaleString` with the `timeZone` option) but you cannot create a new `Date` object from that string.  If you want an object that can actually be set to a different time zone, consider [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).  If you need a solution without a library, you will one day be able to use a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html#Temporal-ZonedDateTime) from the [TC39 Temporal Proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html), which will eventually be part of ECMAScript.
- Beware of calling `console.log` on a `Date` object.  Neither the ECMAScript spec nor the WhatWG Console spec defines the behavior of such a call.  It is undefined behavior.  In some environments, the string output logged is the same as calling `.toString()` on the `Date` object - which will give the local time equivalent of the `Date` object's timestamp, along with a display name for the local time zone.  Other environments will show the same output of calling `.toISOString()`, which will give an ISO-8601 representation of the timestamp in UTC.   Instead of logging `Date` objects, call one of those two functions yourself and log the output.

Comment: thanks this is really helpful, one last question, does this answer account for Daylight savings time?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127122/15358601        return new Date((typeof date === "string" ? New Date(date) : date).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: tzString}));

Comment: `toLocaleString` does when it creates the string, but `new Date(...)` is going to use the *local* time zone's offset and DST rules when parsing that string. That is why you shouldn't use that approach.

Comment: this is my real goal question, maybe you can help, thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66664483/javascript-send-schedule-date-from-local-timezone-to-server-time

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertTZ() {
    return new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles" });
}
console.log(convertTZ());

//Second way
//Hoepfully that's going to be the code that you need.You can change the way that you want to see the date.
function convertTZ() {
    return new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles" ,
  day: "numeric",
  month: "short",
  year: "numeric",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "2-digit"
});
}
console.log(convertTZ(),' America/Los Angeles');
```

Comment: it displays it as a string instead of date, and does not display America/Los Angeles

Comment: can you remove this answer for now? its not working, thank you though

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions
will help to achieve it.

Comment: can you also produce working code? thanks