# Javascript Send Schedule Date From Local Timezone to Server Time

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I am in Hawaii. From Angular, I want to send Pacific Standard Time (PST) to C# Net Core API. It will save it in database and save in Pacific Standard Time. (I didn't create the architecture, just  noting).

The whole Angular Application date/times are written in reference of PST.

Example goal is to Schedule Date at 4:30PM PST

We learned a bug today, if we send a date `"2021-03-17T16:30:00"` , our application creates  `new Date("2021-03-17T16:30:00")` in Hawaii Timezone misinterprets. Then C# probably does the right thing, and converts any time to Pacific Local time  `(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Los_Angeles"))`. Thus we incorrectly convert to 7:30PM.

Our API Request Data type is in Date. Would this solution work? however, I feel last 4th line will not account for Daylight savings, or can create issue.

```js
const inputDate = "2021-03-17T16:30:00";
const pstMoment = moment.tz(inputDate, 'America/Los_Angeles');
const clientTimeZoneName = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
const clientMoment = pstMoment.clone().tz(clientTimeZoneName);
console.log(new Date(clientMoment.format())); // this will send to API
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

Note: Code resolution should not only work in Hawaii, but other global countries which may Not have Daylight Savings Time. Our schedule datepicker utilizes a string storage type (inputDate).

**Typescript class**

```
export interface ScheduleDto { 
   scheduleDate?: Date;

scheduleDate: "2021-03-18T02:30:00.000Z"
```

**C# class**

```
public class ScheduleDto   
{
   public DateTime? ScheduleDate { get; set; }

....

return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(ScheduleDate , TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Comment: hi @RobG Intl.DateTimeFormat will store it as a string, I need to send as Date Type for C# request

Comment: You posted javascript so I assumed javascript, my apologies. :-)

Comment: Why are you doing any conversions at all?  If you send exactly `"2021-03-17T16:30:00"` to the server, then you already have the data you need.  Same on the server side.  No conversion should be required unless you have some other requirement not stated here.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint well the API request needs a date, not string, if I do Date("2021-03-17T16:30:00") it will convert to Hawaii time as specific in description above

Comment: is it best practice to send it as a string?

Comment: All API requests are strings over the wire.  JSON, XML, QueryString, Form Post, unless you are doing some sort of odd binary magic, it's all strings.  If you're constructing a JS `Date` object for some reason, it's just later converting it back to a string somewhere else in your code before sending it to the server.  So - simply - don't.  If you really think you need to create a `Date` object to make a REST call, please edit your question to show us that part of your code as well.

Comment: I added objects above @MattJohnson-Pint

Comment: We would also need to know how that `ScheduleDto` typescript object is serialized.  Can you give us an example of the data as it appears in the HTTP request querystring or body?  Is it, for example, `"2021-03-18T02:30:00Z"`  (the UTC equivalent of 16:30 Hawaii time)?

Comment: hi @MattJohnson-Pint its sent as this, scheduleDate: "2021-03-18T02:30:00.000Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that your current approach on the client-side is just creating a `Date` object like `new Date("2021-03-17T16:30:00")`, which is going to use the local time zone to determine the point-in time you're talking about.  You want it to always be interpreted as Pacific time, but you don't know which offset to use because of DST.

So then, the ultimate answer to your question is - YES, the code you wrote using Moment-timezone, would indeed apply the correct offset.  However, it's a bit verbose.  You don't actually need to do anything with regard to detecting the current local time zone.  You can instead just build the `Date` object with:

```js
moment.tz('2021-03-17T16:30:00', 'America/Los_Angeles').toDate()
```

Given [Moment's project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/), it would be preferred to use Luxon instead (unless you have already extensively used Moment in your project).  In Luxon, that would be:

```js
luxon.DateTime.fromISO('2021-03-17T16:30:00', {zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'}).toJSDate()
```

Or you could use the `zonedTimeToUtc` function from [date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz).

The point is, since you're constructing a `Date` object, you're always sending some string representation of it over the wire.  You appear to be serializing those `Date` objects with `.toISOString()`, which will send the UTC equivalent `"2021-03-18T02:30:00.000Z"`.  Getting that UTC point in time correct is what matters most.

In your .NET code, if you are receiving that value into a `DateTime` object, then its `Kind` property will be set to `Utc` because of the `Z` at the end of the string.  `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` will use the `Kind` property to determine the source time zone for the conversion, and you've supplied the destination time zone as Pacific time.

A much simpler approach would be to *not* use a `Date` object in your client-side code, but rather you would send the intended date and time over the wire instead, without the offset `"2021-03-17T16:30:00"`.  In your .NET code, the `DateTime.Kind` would be `Unspecified`.  Then you wouldn't call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` at all, because you already have the value in the desired time zone.

**Alternatives:**

For the TypeScript data type, You could use a string.

In the future, when [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) is finished and fully integrated into ECMAScript, you could use a `PlainDateTime`.

Comment: awesome, thanks,if I did not use Date object in Typescript client, what is the datatype? string, any?   thanks