# JavaScript: how to get date time at a specified timezone

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, timezone

Is there a way to get a time that is local to a specified timezone in JavaScript? Basically, I'm looking for a way to say, what is the ISO time string of 2pm in New York?

I have a hack to do so, where the `date` is a parse-able date string, and `tz` is a timezone identifier, such as `America/New_York`.

```
function getDateInTZ(date, tz) {
  const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric",
    fractionalSecondDigits: 3,
    timeZone: tz,
  });
  const localDate = new Date(date);
  const localDateAtTZ = new Date(formatter.format(localDate));
  const tzOffset = localDate.getTime() - localDateAtTZ.getTime();
  return new Date(localDate.getTime() + tzOffset);
}
```

and it has the following behavior

```
getDateInTz("2021-07-01 20:05", "America/Chicago").toISOString(); // 2021-07-02T01:05:00.000Z
getDateInTz(new Date("2021-12-05 20:05"), "America/Chicago").toISOString(); // 2021-12-06T02:05:00.000Z

getDateInTz("2021-12-06T02:05:00.000Z", "America/New_York").toISOString(); // 2021-12-06T02:05:00.000Z if local time is NY
getDateInTz("2021-12-06T02:05:00.000Z", "America/New_York").toISOString(); // 2021-12-06T07:05:00.000Z if local time is UTC
```

While the above solution works in Chrome, it doesn't work on Firefox because FF is unable to do `Date.parse` on the output of `formatter.format()`. Which leads me to think that it's not a correct solution.

Has anyone run into this requirement before, and have a good solution for it?

Comment: Perhaps you really want a vanilla JS solution? Though, I'd highly recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone

Comment: @FishSaidNo do you have the code that uses moment-timezone that does what I am mentioning?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630818/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript-and-print-with-correct-timezone

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible without the help of a library like [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon) or [day.js](https://day.js.org/en/)

In luxon this would be the way to go

```js
let local = luxon.DateTime.local();  // 2021-10-31T20:26:15.093+01:00
let localInCT = local.setZone("America/Chicago"); //2021-10-31T14:26:15.093-05:00
```

Have a look at [this project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-5ajnkr?file=script.js) using these methods

Answer (score 1):

We're limited by the JavaScript native Date object here.

The internal state of a Date object is the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC, and no timezone is stored in the Date object.

So, we can create Dates somewhat equivalent to ones created in another timezone, but they won't behave exactly the same:

- The timezone offset for Date.toString() will show the local client timezone (e.g. GMT+0000) rather than the offset in the desired timezone.
- DST rules may not work as expected. We can get the equivalent date for say America/New_York, but DST transitions will obey the local timezone rules and not the New York rules.

Having said that, a variant of the approach you're using will give what I would call *equivalent* dates in the desired timezone.

How we do this:

1. First use [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) to format an ISO timestamp in the desired timezone. We use a hack to do this, passing the 'sv' locale to the function. This will create an ISO timestamp, e.g. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.
2. Pass this timestamp to the Date() constructor.

**TLDR:** This can't *really* be done. But for some contexts and use cases we can *approximate* the desired behaviour. I would recommend using a library like [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) for this purpose.

Example below:

```js
function getDateInTimezone(date, timeZone) {
    // Using a locale of 'sv' formats as an ISO date, e.g. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.
    const timeInTimeZone = date.toLocaleString('sv', { timeZone } );
    // Pass this to the Date constructor
    return new Date(timeInTimeZone);
}

const localTime = new Date();
const timeZoneList = ['Asia/Tokyo', 'Europe/Berlin','America/Los_Angeles'];

console.log(`Local Time: ${localTime.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
for(let timeZone of timeZoneList) {
    const dt = getDateInTimezone(localTime, timeZone);
    console.log(`Time (${timeZone}): ${dt.toLocaleTimeString()}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Timezones in [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) are a lot easier to handle, also when we call .toString() on a Luxon DateTime, we get the correct UTC offset.

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;
const localTime = DateTime.now();
const timeZoneList = ['Asia/Tokyo', 'Europe/Berlin','America/Los_Angeles'];

console.log(`Local Time: ${localTime.toFormat('HH:mm:ssZZ')}`);
for(let zone of timeZoneList) {
    const dt = DateTime.fromMillis(Date.now(), { zone });
    console.log(`Time (${zone}): ${dt.toFormat(' HH:mm:ssZZ')}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.0.2/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-frUCURIeB0OKMPgmDEwT3rC4NH2a4gn06N3Iw6T1z0WfrQZd7gNfJFbHrNsZP38PVXOp6nUiFtBqVvmCj+ARhw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
const actualDate = new Date()
actualDate.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. What you're doing is displaying the date object (in your example, current time) in a different time zone. What I'm asking for is to get a specific time at that time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your question?

```js
function getDateInTZ(date, tz) {
  return new Date(date).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: tz })
}

console.log(getDateInTZ("2021-07-01 20:05", "Asia/Kolkata"))
console.log(getDateInTZ("2021-07-01 20:05", "America/Chicago"))
console.log(getDateInTZ("2021-12-06T02:05:00.000Z", "America/New_York"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't answer my question. First, I need the function to return a Date object, not a string. And second, it doesn't actually do what I need.

```
// expected
getDateInTz("2021-12-06T02:05:00.000Z", "America/New_York").toISOString(); // 2021-12-06T02:05:00.000Z if local time is NY
//actual
getDateInTZ("2021-12-06T02:05:00.000Z", "America/New_York")
'12/5/2021, 9:05:00 PM'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let date = new Date();
let time = date.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour12: true })
```

if we are using hour12 true it will return the time in 12h format else it will return the time in 24h format
make sure we are using **TZ on .env file** it always been a good practice and helps to erase all the extra code.

you can simply use

```
TZ=America/New_York
```